# SQL: Convert GMT timezone to CET

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I am querying the following:

```
SELECT "date" FROM "database"
```

and receive the following table:

```
date
2021-03-08 05:05:31+00
2021-03-08 05:10:31+00
```

The times displayed are in GMT. How can I convert them to CET, taking into account daylight savings?

Comment: [convert_tz](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Comment: I tried this SELECT "date", convert_tz("date", 'GMT', 'CET') FROM "database" but it did not work. Do you know how I would implement this?

Comment: Telling us it doesn't work is not very helpful.  Post your actual code and the result/error message.  The below answer should work.

Comment: Here is the error: ERROR:  function convert_tz(timestamp with time zone, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select "date", convert_tz(date, 'GMT', 'CET')
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883 Character: 16. I think that's because my date includes a time zone? (the +00 part) Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to specify timezone offset in the function, not timezone names:

```
convert_tz(`date`,'+00:00','+10:00')
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3b538/2)

Comment: Would this take into account daylight savings? Also, I tried your suggestion and got this error:  function convert_tz(unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist. 
I think that's because my timestamp has a timezone as well

Comment: Is your column `datetime` or `timestamp`?

Comment: It's a timestamp with timezone.